GOSU query.make Join from primary table twice
I am trying to write the below SQL query utilizing Gosu's Query.make. I tried to join LineItem#TAccount after joining in the transaction table, but it doesn't work.
Here is the error, "column must be a column in the current table object or it must be a foreign key to the current table object. It is from table entity.LineItem to table entity.Transaction"
The problem seems to be when I bring in the transaction table.  I think it is trying to join the transaction table with the TAccount table and the join is from the LineItem table to the Transaction table.
var transactionsFromTransactionQuery = Query.make(LineItem)
        .join(LineItem#TAccount)
        .join(LineItem#Transaction)
        .or(\orCriteria -> {
          orCriteria.compare("Subtype", Relop.Equals, Transaction.TC_CHARGEPAIDFROMUNAPPLIED)
          orCriteria.compare("Subtype", Relop.Equals, Transaction.TC_CHARGEWRITTENOFF)
          orCriteria.compare("Subtype", Relop.Equals, Transaction.TC_INITIALCHARGETXN)
        })
        .join("TAccountContainer", PolicyPeriod, "HiddenTAccountContainer")
        .compare(PolicyPeriod#PolicyNumberLong, Relop.Equals, "My policy number")

SELECT txn.* 
FROM bc_transaction txn
inner join bc_lineitem li on li.TransactionID = txn.ID
inner join bc_taccount ta on ta.id = li.TAccountID
inner join bc_policyperiod pp on pp.HiddenTAccountContainerID = ta.TAccountContainerID
inner join bctl_transaction tSub
    on txn.Subtype = tSub.ID
where pp.PolicyNumberLong = 'myPolicyNumber'
and tSub.TYPECODE in ('ChargePaidFromUnapplied','ChargeWrittenOff','InitialChargeTxn')```


You run into this a lot with entities that heavily utilize inheritance and have 1 logical database table that holds values for many entity types that are children of the top-level base entity. I have seen this a lot when writing queries for the Contact table where I have to create separate queries for the Company sub-entity and the Person sub-entity. The best solution in this case might be doing 3 separate queries for each transaction typ.

Can you clarify what isn't working in what you're showing?  You want the or condition to be included in the "JOIN... ON" clause rather than the WHERE clause?  I can't figure out what the functional difference in the result set would be, but then again I don't run a DB engine in my head!  :-)  As Steve said, you can write three distinct queries and UNION them together, but I'm just not clear on why what gets generated here doesn't work.

@MartinAavik - I updated the gosu query to reflect what I am trying to achieve and I provided the error message along with what I think the problem is.

With the updates and additional information about your issue I think I see what you're having an issue with.  Specifically, the way you're chaining operations isn't respecting the context you think it is.  Each join returns a table object for the joined entity, not the root entity of the query.make().  So your later operations are trying to reference columns from a different entity than is in scope.
Please review this version of the query and see if it works for you.  Note that I don't have a BC studio up to validate my rewrite, so I might have the join references on the wrong table, but hopefully I've got it close.


var transactionsFromTransactionQuery = Query.make(LineItem)
var tacctTable = transactionsFromTransactionQuery.join(LineItem#TAccount)
var tranTable = transactionsFromTransactionQuery.join(LineItem#Transaction)
    .or(\orCriteria -> {
      orCriteria.compare("Subtype", Relop.Equals, Transaction.TC_CHARGEPAIDFROMUNAPPLIED)
      orCriteria.compare("Subtype", Relop.Equals, Transaction.TC_CHARGEWRITTENOFF)
      orCriteria.compare("Subtype", Relop.Equals, Transaction.TC_INITIALCHARGETXN)
    })
var polPerTable = tacctTable.join("TAccountContainer", PolicyPeriod, "HiddenTAccountContainer")
    .compare(PolicyPeriod#PolicyNumberLong, Relop.Equals, "My policy number")




This will work in BC. I just tested this by creating a simple API containing the query. If you start the query builder like Query.make(LineItem).withLogSQL(true) then you can see the resultant SQL query. I will post that in another comment. I would just also suggest to Brandon that he always use the property reference literals instead of strings (Transaction#Subtype vs "Subtype"). Also I had to use typekey.Transaction.TC_CHARGEPAIDFROMUNAPPLIED to avoid the ambiguity between the Transaction typelist and entity.

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT 1 as countCol FROM bc_lineitem gRoot INNER JOIN (bc_taccount taccount_0 INNER JOIN (bc_policyperiod policyperiod_1) ON taccount_0.TAccountContainerID = policyperiod_1.HiddenTAccountContainerID) ON taccount_0.ID = gRoot.TAccountID INNER JOIN (bc_transaction transaction_2) ON transaction_2.ID = gRoot.TransactionID WHERE policyperiod_1.PolicyNumberLong = ? AND policyperiod_1.Retired = 0 AND transaction_2.Retired = 0 AND ((((transaction_2.Subtype = ?) OR (transaction_2.Subtype = ?) OR (transaction_2.Subtype = ?)))))
